# perl par-packer exe file sleep() not working

Tags: perl, sleep, par, perl-packager

`hello.pl` is a file which works fine:

```
print "Hello World";
sleep(5);
```

When I convert that to `hello.exe` using par-packer, window will sleep for 5 sec but won't print "Hello World" - which is actually printed after 5 sec and window exits.

Any solution is appreciated. I want the print to be displayed for 5 sec.

Comment: `STDOUT->autoflush();` http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be an issue of flushing the buffer to `STDOUT`. You can either manually flush before the sleep with

```
STDOUT->flush() # a specific instance of $filehandle->flush()
```

or you can ask that the that file handle be automatically flushed for you.

```
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

Also you can turn that off with a `0` as the parameter.

Lastly there's a less readable special variable `$|` which you can assign `1` to if you're doing some kind of one-liner or code-golfing.